# Show an image over (on top of) a webcam feed actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, webcam, camera-overlay

So I have searched the web for about two days and don't have a clue where to start. I'm pretty new to flash (started 2 days ago). I'm a 3rd year CS student and I'm kind off stuck on this. 
It'd would be great if anyone could tell me if it was possible in flash or not? 
and If it was then probably share a tutorial?
If not then kindly mention how(using what) can this be done?

Appreciate the help :)

Comment: I'm sure you have a video object added to stage right? then you can also add a Bitmap with your image after adding video, then it will be on top - move it to the same place and you will have it overlaid.

Comment: had no clue, it was this simple. Thanks :)